# How can I give a flag to PHAsset?

Tags: ios, iphone, photos, photosframework, phasset

I want to mark a video as uploaded when I upload that to server. I am using Photos framework to fetch videos from a PHCollection. I can't find a way to mark video as uploaded so that I can distinguish between both the types of videos uploaded and not uploaded.
Please help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PHAsset`'s `localIdentifier` property to distinguish uploaded and not uploaded media. When you finish uploading, store the identifier somewhere in your app to mark the media as uploaded. 
Documentation states that `localIdentifier` is:

```
A unique string that persistently identifies the object. (read-only)
```

Hope this helps!

P.S.: `localIdentifier` comes from `PHObject` which `PHAsset` inherits.